# PostgreSQL 9.1 won't restore because "a user is connected"

Tags: redhat, postgresql, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger, database-restore

I'm transferring a database as part of transferring a website. I've not used PostgreSQL before, so assume that I don't know much about it (I primarily use MySQL). We cannot directly connect the machines to use the `pg_dump -h host1 dbname | psql -h host2 dbname` trick.

I've used `pg_dumpall -c` to dump all databases into an SQL file with DROP commands. I've then downloaded and uploaded the backup to the destination server via SCP. But I cannot import the same exported file using `psql -U root postgres backup.sql` because of this error:

```
DROP DATABASE
ERROR:  database "exfi" is being accessed by other users
DETAIL:  There are 1 other session(s) using the database.
```

I suspect that this is caused by the Ruby on Rails app maintaining a persistent connection to the database. We're using Phusion Passenger 3.0.11 with Apache 2.2.21 on RHEL 16.

I've used `touch tmp/restart.txt` to tell Passenger to restart the website before the import, but it doesn't appear to kill the existing worker.

Answer (score 0):

Because of Phusion Passenger, Apache needs to be shut down before you can restore the database. You can use `apachectl graceful-stop` before restoring the database, then `apachectl start` after. There is probably a more graceful way to do a "System Maintenance" landing page during the process, but I'll let a real sysadmin chime in on that (and anything else I missed).